# scikit-learn: cloning a prefitted estimator for learning_curve, GridSearchCV etc

Tags: python, scikit-learn, clone, deep-copy, grid-search

How can I force sklearn's GridSearchCV, learning_curve, etc to deepcopy a base estimator instead of cloning it?

A bit more information:

My custom classifier takes a fitted base estimator as a parameter during initialization. During fitting, it uses the base estimator to learn quicker (in the context of domain adaptation).
When I tune the parameters of my classifier using GridSearchCV(), for example, the classifier is clone()'ed internally for each configuration. However, clone() does not preserve the prefitted base estimator as it only clones its parameters (but not its fitted variables).

I believe, although not quite sure, this is somewhat related to:

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6451 and perhaps
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1626

If sklearn doesn't provide a solution, any ideas on working around it for the time being?